# Reversing a string

Tags: c#, strings, interview-questions, comparative-review

I had this as an interview question, and the interviewer pointed this out. Here's what I wrote:

```
//C# Syntax here
public string Reverse(string s)
{
    char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
    int idx = 0;
    int endIdx = s.Length - 1;
    for(; idx < endIdx; ++idx, --endIdx)
    {
        char temp = arr[idx];
        arr[idx] = arr[endIdx];
        arr[endIdx] = temp;
    }
    return arr.ToString();
}
```

However, the interviewer was asking if I should have changed it to this:

```
//C# Syntax here
public string Reverse(string s)
{
    char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
    int idx = 0;
    int endIdx = s.Length - 1;
    while(idx < endIdx)
    {
        char temp = arr[idx];
        arr[idx] = arr[endIdx];
        arr[endIdx] = temp;
        ++idx;
        --endIdx;
    }
    return arr.ToString();
}
```

Personally, I like the first version, because it puts all of the machinery which controls the loop into the loop statement. One can insert `continue` or `break` or `return` statements into the loop without it breaking things.

However, some programmers dislike putting that stuff into the `for`, because they think it's being too "clever".

What do you consider best-practice for this?

Answer (score 14):

I would argue against changing it. This seems to be exactly what for-loops were invented for. Also, why not put the initialization in the for loop?

I would have also preferred

```
for(int idx=0; idx < endIdx; ++idx, --endIdx) {
```

if only so that I don't have to scan up and down the page looking for the initialization  of `idx`.

Comment: Because this was on a whiteboard, and I was running out of space :P (And because that makes the FOR line long)

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Ok, whiteboard space constraints are fair ;)

Comment: Why not: `for (int idx = 0, endIdx = s.Length-1; idx < endIdx; ++idx, --endIdx) { ... }`?  That way you get **all** the loop controls in the loop.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I prefer having all loop counters/conditionals inside the for-loop, and if that makes the for-loop line too long, I'd break them into three lines.

Answer (score 12):

I personally would go with the `while` loop. I'm not against `for` loops at all, but yours is different than most, and caused me to reread to catch up. I am used to seeing, as I imagine most people are, `for` loops with an initializer and only one statement to iterate:

`for (int i = startValue; i < endValue; i++) {...}`

To me, you're already initializing outside of the loop statement (as you said, you prefer to keep things in the loop statement), so you may as well use a `while` so people expect initialization to be elsewhere. Same with using this construct:

`++idx, --endIdx`

I'm not *expecting* this sort of thing in a `for` loop. I would be more aware something like this might happen in a `while` loop.

Summary: I personally think the `while` loop is more readable, because I have certain expectations for `for` loops. If this is true of the other people who will read/maintain the code, I don't know.

Comment: Do you have rationale other than "this is the one I like"?

Comment: I feel like it adheres better to user expectations, where "users" in this case are other people who will work with the code. Now yes, I base that on what I personally expect, as detailed in my answer. The `for` loop you have was more difficult for me to read, because it did things I don't normally see in `for` loops, but more frequently see in `while` loops. So yes, it's pretty subjective, but not just because I fancy `while` loops or have a thing against the word "for" or something :)

Comment: Okay, that's reasonable. +1.

Answer (score 11):

That code looks pretty complex for the trivial task it does.

1. No need to convert the string to a char array. By not calling ToCharArray() [you get rid of an extra copy of data](http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/archive/2004/06/10/153175.aspx).
2. Poorly named variables IMHO. (The convention for index is `i`.)
3. No need to substract from the end index. (which I prefer to call `length` as a convention)
4. You shouldn't call `ToString()`, but use the constructor of string. Your code outputs the typename instead of the reversed string.

Altogether:

```
public string Reverse( string s )
{
    int length = s.Length;
    char[] reversed = new char[ length ];

    for ( int i = 0; i < length; ++i )
    {
        reversed[ i ] = s[ length - 1 - i ];
    }

    return new string( reversed );
}
```

And of course, the proper solution would be using [`Reverse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx) from `IEnumerable`. But that wasn't part of the question perhaps.

```
return new string( s.Reverse().ToArray() );
```

---

An interesting article which compares different reverse string implementations [can be found here](http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/archive/2004/06/10/153175.aspx).

It's a pity you got referred to here from Programmers.SE, IMHO you do touch some points which are perfectly discussable on Programmers.

Comment: 1. Yes there is. Just because you did it a different way doesn't mean you didn't do it. 2. I strongly disagree. Single letter variable names make me cringe. The counter is primarily an array index, and it's name reflects that. 3. Okay, I agree that's nicer. 4. Why does it matter? 5. **READ THE QUESTION. I'm not talking about this specific implementation of `Reverse`. I'm talking about use of logic in `for` loops. Reverse is the algorithm I happened to be using as an example when the question came up, but critiquing how I threw this together in 30 seconds is not the point.**

Comment: 1. By not calling `ToCharArray()` you [get rid of an extra copy of data](http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/archive/2004/06/10/153175.aspx). 2. The name of a variable should be only as important as the scope it is in. The for loop indexer is a perfect example of a small scope. If you don't like `i`, I'd still prefer `index` over `idx`, but I know of practically noone who doesn't use `i`. 4. Your code outputs the typename instead of the reversed string. 5. When you post on Code Review, expect a code review. If you want to discuss a general topic go to Programmers.

Comment: I didn't post to code review. I posted to programmers. It got moved here. (Sorry for shouting last night -- I was half asleep and not thinking straight.)

Comment: This answer is buggy. It does not accomplish the required task: to reverse the String. What it does do, is reverse the string twice, leaving the string in its original state. The condition of the loop should be something like `i < (length / 2)`

Comment: @rolfl? Huh? No it doesn't? `length / 2` only reverses half of the string. Perhaps you are confused because I mention the `return new string( s.Reverse().ToArray() );` in the end? This is a separate solution from the one above, reusing already built-in framework code.

Comment: @StevenJeuris - For a string of lenght 4, you start at i=0, and you swap `reversed[0]` and `reversed[3]`, then `reversed[1]` and `reversed[2]`, then `reversed[2]` and `reversed[1]` and finally `reversed[3]` and `reversed[0]`. You have double-reversed it, hence made no change...

Comment: Sorry @rolfl but this answer is not wrong. Once an index is set in the `reversed` array it is not modified again. The for-loop reads from `s` and writes to `reversed`.

Comment: @rolfl I don't swap anything (as in the OPs solution). I iterate across all chars in reverse order, for simplicity reasons. Performance wise one might be better than the other, but I'd need to run into a performance issue prior to refactoring that.

Comment: Ahh... thanks all.. down-vote removed. In my head I had it that you were reversing the chars 'in place', but they are coming from different arrays.

Comment: Agree with 2. Really poor variable names all through from OP.

Answer (score 3):

The primary consideration when deciding what to put in the for-loop header should be whether the for-loop header conveys the structure of the loop.  The three elements (initializer; condition; update) should form a coherent story.

I would express your function like this:

```
public string Reverse(string s)
{
    char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0, j = s.Length - 1; i < j; ++i, --j)
    {
        char swap = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = swap;
    }
    return arr.ToString();
}
```

From just the for-loop header, a reasonably experienced programmer can recognize the idiom for stepping two array indices until they meet in the middle.  By convention, `i` and `j` are array indices; you don't need the `…Idx` Hungarian suffix.

In comparison, the interviewer's proposal looks unstructured.  I feel like I have to mentally decompile it back into the for-loop above to understand what is going on.

I've also renamed `temp` to `swap` as a silent "comment".

---

You might be wondering, to what extreme can you pack logic into the for-loop header?  In practice, I've never seen more a good for-loop header that involved more than two variables.  The probable explanation is that the condition usually involves a binary comparison operator.  A third variable would therefore usually be "off-topic" for the header.

Two other guidelines you might want to use are:

- If you can fill in all three parts of the header (initializer; condition; update), then a for-loop is probably appropriate.
- If the loop body surreptitiously updates the iteration variable, such that the header tells a misleading or incomplete story, then the iteration should probably *not* be done using a for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

@Billy ONeal : I strongly believe that this is a matter of taste. Robert C. Martin states in [Clean Code](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882) that software developers like to use obfuscated code to "show off" and I agree with him. I also liked to do that until I started to work on my first complex project and I realized that extra mind mappings are not necessary.

That been said, my option will be to use the `while()` loop; I think that we can go here with the same principle which is applied to a method: the loop should do one thing and one thing only (personal opinion extrapolated from [Clean Code](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882)). So, if I look at a piece of code after 4 hours of endless debugging, it might feel easier to read (I only formatted the code for easier reading):

```
     //top-down reading per loop
     while (UnswitchedCharactersExist())
     {
         SwitchCharacters(arr, idx, endIdx);
         IncrementStartIndex();
         DecrementEndIndex();
     }
```

than:

```
     //read the initializer, the condition, the code block and go back up for the update
    //after that read the condition, the code block and go back up for the update
    for(; UnswitchedCharactersExist(); IncrementStartIndex(), DecrementEndIndex())
    {
        SwitchCharacters(arr, idx, endIdx); 
    }
```

My 2 cents on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I can't really warm up to either version. I guess that to me, reversing a sequence is *so* obviously a fold, that anything which *doesn't* implement it as a fold looks just plain weird.

I would have expected to see something much more like this:

```
public static string Reverse(this string s)
{
    return s.Aggregate("", (acc, el) => el + acc);
}
```

I.e. implemented as a left fold.

After all, reversing any sequence (not just strings) is really just the same as

```
foldl (flip (:)) []
```

Comment: That performs horribly though (in the first case -- you've turned a constant time algorithm into an O(N^2) one, with a memory allocation for the whole string for each character!)). I don't know what `fold1` is. (Nor have I ever heard of the concept)

Comment: More to the point, this doesn't answer my question -- I'm not asking about this specific implementation of reverse, I'm asking about the general case of embedding logic more complicated than "n + 1" in a for loop condition.

Comment: Err.. where I said "constant time" above I meant "linear time".

Comment: In a functional language, a fold or more explicit recursion, would often replace a loop.  Single-Linked-Lists are also very common in functional languages, where a string would be a linked-list of char.  And actually, a properly done functional algorithm would still be O(n), since you'd go over the list, building a new list in reverse order as you went.

Comment: Such as: `reverse first :: rest = (reverse rest) :: first` And pretend I added the case for empty list.  `::` is the "cons" operator.  Check out F# for functional programming in .NET.

Comment: Also, technically, the loop example is still faster because you're performing an in-place swap.  So the mutable loop code take n/2 time while the recursion takes n time.  There may be a clever way to do it functionally that I'm not aware of that evens it up.

Comment: @CodexArcanum: The linked list solution is still O(n^2), because to do the append the list must be transversed to find the last element (unless you're keeping around a pointer to the last element, which this implementation doesn't seem to do). Linked list is a horrendously bad data structure in any case -- I still wonder why a better compromise like C++'s `deque` isn't a common primitive available in more languages..

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't think it matters. For a function this simple, I can think of several similar implementations:

- Have an index to the front and to the back in a for loop
- Have an index to the front and to the back in a while loop
- Have a single index, and calculate the offset from the end of the loop each time round the loop
- All of the possibilities above, but increment/decrement a pointer to char, rather than an index into an array (at least in C, can you do this in C# ?)

And probably several more. I think that the right answer is whatever seems most readable (unless it's EGREGIOUSLY inefficient), and if you think it may be called in an inner loop leave a comment saying (a) don't do that and (b) suggest what changes you'd think about making then, but you'd most likely need to be sure, the function is too simple for your common sense to be much guide about what's faster.

I agree your answer has the potential problems the interviewer described, and his has the potential problems you described. I think either is more than fine, so long as you can see the potential issues, I don't think they can be improved into a single "best" answer.

Comment: "can you do this in C#" <-- Not really. It's possible but you'll have to go into "unsafe code" -- which means your code won't run several places, i.e. Silverlight, because unsafe code requires full trust. Again though, **I'm not talking about this specific case of `reverse`**. I'm talking about the general case -- this is just the algorithm I happened to be talking about when the general question came up.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to write this as a comment but got out of space, so...

In general lines, I agree with Peter Leppert; I think the while is more idiomatic here.

Of course C for syntax allows you to use the first case, and in simple functions I don't think it really matters, but then, C allows you implementing mostly any function in the header of a for loop with an empty body, and that doesn't makes it a good idea ;-).

Your for header was

```
for(; idx < endIdx; ++idx, --endIdx)
```

just because you got out of space in the whiteboard. In a computer it would have been more like the following:

```
for(int idx = 0, endIdx = s.Length - 1; idx < endIdx; ++idx, --endIdx)
```

Ok, fair enough. Now you find you need another control variable for a new functionality:

```
for(int idx = 0, endIdx = s.Length - 1, otherVar = FunctionCall(param1, param2); idx < endIdx && otherVar < AnotherFunctionCall(param1); ++idx, --endIdx, otherVar += 5)
```

What now, uh? It gets ugly very quickly. This doesn't scale up, so, where do you put the line? Character limit in header? Only two control variables?

That's why I would only do the classic for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxI; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

and use a while for everything else.

Anyway, with that question the interviewer was probably trying to see how you think rather than testing your programming capabilities.

Comment: But if you limit the for loop to that only, then there's little reason for it to exist at all -- `foreach` handles that. (i.e. `foreach(var idx = Enumerable.Range(0, maxI)) { ... }`) (That syntax isn't 100% correct but it gets the idea)

Comment: @Billy Oneal: Sorry, you're right, I was thinking in C++ where we still don't have a for each, so I didn't use the best example. However, it still applies if you don't want to process every item in the list, or need to do so in specific order (i.e. traverse a list backwards)

Comment: @BillyONeal, @JaimePardos is probably correct that the interviewer just wanted to see your thought process on tackling this problem. IMHO, I like the `for` for the simple reason that it's easier to read and you don't have to worry about setting the start and end index for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Although both for and while are loops and both will work but as a general guideline, for loop is better suited in this case because

- When we know the number of iterations in advance, we should use for loop as it allows initiation, condition and increment to be done in one line.
- Index variable (idx in this case), is more appropiately scoped, why should we increase the scope of idx when this is meant only to be used within the loop.
- Unlike while loop, statements like continue, etc. (if required) can be used without any issues.

While loop should be usually used if we don't know number of iterations in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to go back to the context that this was an interview question.

When I interview people, I try to ask questions that don't have one "right" answer - that's more like a trivia test, which is actually fairly useless to me.  Instead, I'll ask a question that requires more of an opinion response, watch the candidate, and look for them to apply logical thinking to the problem.

If you can justify that it should be a for loop, and your code is readable, good answer.  If you can justify that it should be a while loop, and your code is readable, that's also a good answer.  But if you say "it should be a for loop because that's the right way," that's just spewing out dogma and doesn't demonstrate independent thought.  It's a less mature answer.  Not that it's wrong, but if I'm trying to figure out if you're a starting programmer or an experienced engineer, it's a clue.

By the way, another really good answer is to say "In my code I'd use Reverse() on the array, because it's already tested."  An employer generally does not want to pay you to reinvent the wheel, and as an interviewer I'd appreciate the depth of your experience that shows.

Answer (score -2):

All things aside, I believe that these two pieces of code function differently. The first is predecrement, the second is post.

I would agree that for loops make this specific application more obfuscated (not by much, but it is certainly less clear). I recommend using for loops primarily for iterating linearly through a collection with the intent of going from some start to an end, where both of these points are known/fixed before the loop starts.

I think that the for loop is a completely valid approach for something like this though. If you find yourself making a for loop and placing an if statement nearly in the beginning of it, then you may want to consider using a while loop.

Comment: Erm, no, both cases are preincrement.